# php References in array

Tags: php, reference

I suggested that the last output showed me the same output as was before. But for uncovered reasons for me the 3d element became equal to the second one. Could you help me with some explanations?

[image]

```
~$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $a = [['q' => 1, 'p' => 5], ['q' => 2, 'p' => 10], ['q' => 3, 'p' => 15]];
php > foreach ($a as &$item) { $item['p'] += 1; }
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [q] => 1
            [p] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [q] => 2
            [p] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [q] => 3
            [p] => 16
        )

)
php > foreach ($a as $item) { print_r($item); }
Array
(
    [q] => 1
    [p] => 6
)
Array
(
    [q] => 2
    [p] => 11
)
Array
(
    [q] => 2
    [p] => 11
)
```

Comment: The issue is $item survives as a variable even after the first foreach loop.

Comment: Yes I know. And I can manage with it lots of ways with unset or using another name of counter. But still why only the last element brokes? I am very curious about it.

Comment: Okey, I got it. It's because the last element still reference to $item and changes with it all the time. Ty.

Comment: Yes, notice that last array with a `&` sign in this link https://onlinephp.io/c/926ab

Answer (score 0):

This is because references can be tricky. `$item` becomes reference to first, then second and finally to the last element of the array. And it stays a reference to the last element of the array.

Now when we get to the second `foreach`, `$item` gets assigned the first, then second and then to the value of the last element of the array. But remember that the `$item` is still a reference to the last element. That means the the `$a[2]` gets assigned the value of `$a[0]`, then `$a[1]` and finally `$a[2]`.

When you print `$a[2]` the last iteration, it just got assigned the value of `$a[1]` because of the previous iteration :)

To visualize it let me write it like this:

After the first `foreach`, a reference to last element of `$a` is stored into `$item` like so:

```
$item = &$a[2];
```

Then the second foreach does the following behind the scenes:

First iteration:

`$item = $a[0];`

Which means `$a[2] = $a[0]` because of the reference. But it's not printed so you don't see it.

Second iteration:

`$item = $a[1];`

Which means `$a[2] = $a[1]` but again you do not print the last value and you cannot see it.

Now the final iteration:

`$item = $a[2]` But `$a[2]` is already equal to `$a[1]` from the previous iteration.